# Receive Events in a javascript and print it in a separate window?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a pushlet in my project which receives the push events (i.e.,) if a user click on some buttons it will get the action and sends the message to the main jsp page through a javascript. Now, i have received datas through the pushlet and retrieved those in a javascript.

```
function setUserDataEvent(UserDataEvent) {
try {
   alert(UserDataEvent);
}
catch(er) {
}
}
```

Where userDataEvent is the event which i received through pushlet. I am getting continuous alerts like for eg.,(a=b) and then (c=d). I have to receive get those values and then print those in a separate window in javascript using window.open()....
Any suggestions???????

Comment: I think you can create an html page and build your data formatting for printing in there and then pass your data in query string binding it from query string using window.location.search and in the window.onload event fire the print() method to print your page with data // that if i get u right if what i'm saying is true tell me for more brief with code

Comment: I have already posted the answer and its working fine. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to go over a cookie.
Save the event data in a cookie, then open the window and then, in your script in the window, read the data and delete the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at a solution and its working fine!!!!!

```
var testWindow;
var testData="";
function setUserDataEvent(UserDataEvent) {
try {
if(!testData) {
   testData = UserDataEvent;
} else {
   testData += UserDataEvent;
}
if(!testWindow) {
   var x = 235;
   var y = 370;
   testWindow = window.open('','q',"location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resize=no,width=" + x + ",height=" + y);
}
   testWindow.document.write(testData);
   testWindow.document.close();
   testWindow.focus();


}
catch (er)
{

}
}
```